# Censoring moving objects in video: How to speed up Mask Path in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere, effects, mask, memory

In Adobe Premiere Pro, Mask Path under Effect Controls can be used to let a [censor effect](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=adobe%20premiere%20mask%20path) ("Camera Blur" or "Mosaic" effects) travel or track through the remaining frames of the video. However, Mask Path takes a long time to run and is very slow. If Mask Path were applied to an hour-long .mp4 file, for example, it would probably have to sit for an entire day or two to complete.

What hardware components would boost the speed at which Mask Path completes its course? Should the focus be on having a maximum amount of RAM (like 64 GB RAM), having large hard drive space, or something else?

Besides Adobe Premiere, are there more economical programs, or techniques, tailored for censoring faces?

Comment: Tracking algorithm speed is often heavily correlated with the area of the source pattern.  Try tracking a smaller area, or tracking a proxy version of the footage, and applying the results to the full resolution.

Comment: it is already a fairly small area (eyes rectangle). which hardware should I focus on improving? RAM, core processor, or other part?